# what is the best multi-threading technique in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-3.5

I'm developing an application that is running a lot of TcpListener tasks
using c# with .net 3.5 on windows server 2008

the TcpListener task is:

1. listening
   to get an xml message
2. read an ID
   from it
3. send a command to a
   specific camera based on the ID to
   take a snapshot and store it in a
   folder

This is meant to execute within 1 second so I can take a snapshot with the camera. I've got a delay in executing this task, using the following code:

```
private Thread listen_thread;

    public void start_listen()
    {
            this.listen_thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(save_data));
            this.listen_thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
            this.listen_thread.Start();

    }
    private void save_data()
    {
        //work to be done
    }
```

Is this the best multi-threading technique to use? This application is running on a on dell poweredge 2900
with 2 quad core prosessor, and I think it could go faster. How might I be able to improve the latency of this code?

thats the code for the tcplistener

```
Int32 port = controller_port;
        try
        {
            //this server ip
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse(this_ip);
            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
            server.Start();
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
            String data = null;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.Write("Connected!");
                data = null;
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                int i;
                string add_data = "";
                Console.Write("Waiting...!");
                while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string full_row = "";
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                        Console.Write("Received from controller: " + data);
                        add_data += data;
                    }
                    catch{}
                }
            }
         }
```

then i divide it to get the ID .

Comment: Where is your `TcpListener` code?

Comment: Is your application CPU bound or I/O bound? Do you have many concurrent accesses or just a single access at a time?

Comment: The code shown doesn't help us appreciate anything important... I think the TCP code (or network stream code, or socket code; whatever) is going to be important here...

Comment: my application is CPU Bound. and i have many thread working in the same time but i don't know if it's a concurrent accesses or a single access at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear at all

1. how you receive requests
2. upon what you parallelize the application

It **seems** that you listen on different sockets and assign a thread on each of them.

I think this is a poor choice, because you can't control the parallelism degree.

You could instead have just one thread that nondeterministically listens on all sockets and assigns the connection to a thread pool, configured to simultaneously run at most n threads, where n is the parallelism degree of your machine (if you have a dual quadcore, n is equal to 8).

Comment: i'm listen to a port on this server.

Comment: ok..i changed it..what i'm doing is listening to port on this server,then when message come it been read as xml then divide the xml and get the id from it..all this in one thread.after that i call the image in anther thread to be able to read the next xml message without the need to wait for the image to be capture . that's creating about 150 thread.i will try ur advice now and hope it will be faster.thanks for ur help

Answer (score 1):

These methods have strikingly wrong names.  start_listen() doesn't start listening.  save_data() cannot possibly save any data until at least a connection is established.  Which requires the client code to start up first and make the connection.  Sure, one second is quickly gone with that.  Starting a thread doesn't take more than a fraction of a millisecond when there's a core available.

Focus on the code that's missing in your snippet.